# JSON object is parsed correctly yet I get undefined when trying to search within the JSON and not just call it as a whole

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Here is my JSON code. I know it has been parsed and nothing is wrong with the code itself. What I have a problem with is if I try to say jsonwordlist.Nouns[0] I get an error saying 'cannot read property 0 of undefined.' I have looked everywhere to try and solve this but honestly can't find anything. Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help.

```
[{

    "Nouns": [
        {
            "nominative": "villa",
            "genitive": "villae",
            "gender": "f",
            "definition": "house",
            "photo": "http://fillmurray.com/200/200",
            "derivitive": "village"
        },

        {
            "nominative": "villa",
            "genitive": "villae",
            "gender": "f",
            "definition": "house",
            "photo": "http://fillmurray.com/200/200",
            "derivitive": "village"
        }
    ],
    "Adjectives": [
        {
            "masculine": "laetus",
            "feminine": "laeta",
            "nueter": "laetum",
            "definition": "happy",
            "derivitive": ""
        },

        {
            "masculine": "iratus",
            "feminine": "irata",
            "nueter": "iratum",
            "definition": "angry",
            "derivitive": "irritate"
        }
    ],
    "Verbs": [
        {
            "pp1": "audio",
            "pp2": "audire",
            "pp3": "audivi",
            "pp4": "auditus",
            "definition": "to hear",
            "derivitive": "audio"
        },

        {
            "pp1": "curro",
            "pp2": "currere",
            "pp3": "cucurri",
            "pp4": "cursus",
            "definition": "to run",
            "derivitive": "concur"
        }
    ],
    "Adverbs": [
        {
            "latin_form": "aliter",
            "definition": "otherwise"
        }
    ],
    "Conjunctions": [
        {
            "latin_form": "quod",
            "definition": "as"
        }
    ],
    "Prepositions": [
        {
            "latin_form": "sine",
            "definition": "without"
        }
    ]

}]
```

Comment: what happens if you do `jsonwordlist[0].Nouns[0]` also can you post the entire variable declaration by that i mean 
`jsonworldlist = stuff`

Comment: Type just `jsonwordlist` in the console. What do you see? Obviously not an object with a property called `Nouns`. What else is it?

Comment: Why is this such a common problem? Parsing JSON is easy: when you see `[` it's an array, so you use `[index]` to index it. When you see `{` it's an object, you use `.property`. Don't you see the `[` at the very beginning?

Comment: and if you do control the source...the outer `[]` array doesn't seem needed and you could just return the single object within it

Comment: `console.log(someVariable)` is Your friend or more brutal... `alert(someVariable)`

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains one object, that object contains multiple arrays. You need to look at spot `0` in the array for your object first.

For example, this should produce a popup with the word `villa`:

`alert(jsonwordlist[0].Nouns[0].nominative);`

See here for more: https://jsfiddle.net/Legn45hc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You put your json in an arrar so you can access noun with

```
jsonwordlist[0].Nouns[0]
```